# How to debug add-on main.js, not just content scripts for Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

My extension code is layed-out like this in the file system.  I'm trying to write an Add-on SDK extension because of its restartless properties.

I'm able to debug, set breakpoints in my launch.js and proc.js code, but so far I haven't been able to set a break point in the main.js.

Any idea why the main.js doesn't show up under 'sources' when in debug mode?  or what I may be missing?  I'm using firefox developer edition on

\sergixten
    \lib
       -main.js
    \data
      -launch.js
      -proc.js

Thanks for the help/hints!

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Addon Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger)

Add-on Debugger is available since Firefox 31. Simply enable it (see on the MDN page how to) and then from Addons Manager, click debug on your addon.

Comment: Thank you, Opti!! Dunno how I missed that, this really helps a bunch!!  Merry Christmas!!, or as we say around here Féliz Navidad!!